# How to show Notification popup only once in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I'm  working on  Angularjs. I need to show the notification popup only once, but my  popup is showing multiple times as i  enter values in textbox.

Here is my piece of code.

```
  $scope.AmountAddition = function() {
                var contributionAmt = $scope.search_form.amount;
                $scope.search_form.paymentBasic.totalContributionAmountCollected = $scope.search_form.amount;
                 if(contributionAmt >= 50000)
                {
                     notificationFactory.info("Kindly enter Pancard number");
                }
           }
```

How to show the popup only once when i enter amount more than 50000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a flag `$scope.isFirstTime` in the beginning of the `controller` and set it after you show the notification

```
if(contributionAmt >= 50000 && $scope.isFirstTime)
{
    notificationFactory.info("Kindly enter Pancard number");
    $scope.isFirstTime = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable to know if the pop-up has been openned once:

```
$scope.alreadyOpenned = false; 

$scope.AmountAddition = function() {
    var contributionAmt = $scope.search_form.amount;
    $scope.search_form.paymentBasic.totalContributionAmountCollected = $scope.search_form.amount;
    if(contributionAmt >= 50000 && !$scope.alreadyOpenned) {
        $scope.alreadyOpenned = true;
        notificationFactory.info("Kindly enter Pancard number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$scope.isOpenned = false;     
$scope.AmountAddition = function() {
    var contributionAmt = $scope.search_form.amount;
    $scope.search_form.paymentBasic.totalContributionAmountCollected = $scope.search_form.amount;
    if(contributionAmt >= 50000 && !$scope.alreadyOpenned) {        
        notificationFactory.info("Kindly enter Pancard number");
        $scope.isOpenned = true;
    }
}
```

But your value is above 50000, At first time popup will show. Next time you are give 40000 and again give above 50000 the popup will not show.

If u need above scenario you can use if else..

```
if(contributionAmt >= 50000 && !$scope.alreadyOpenned) {        
            notificationFactory.info("Kindly enter Pancard number");
            $scope.isOpenned = true;
        }else{
 $scope.isOpenned = false;
}
```